Plugin for local video embed for CKeditor 5
I have problem i need to implement local video embed into ckeditor
https://github.com/Technologie-Visao/ckeditor5-video This plugin should work but i have problem with installing it.
When i am using yarn add -D @visao/@visao/ckeditor5-video
I get this message in my terminal
yarn add v1.22.22
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "cosmiconfig@8.2.0" is incompatible with requested version "cosmiconfig@^5.0.0"
warning Resolution field "cosmiconfig@8.2.0" is incompatible with requested version "cosmiconfig@^7.0.0"
warning Resolution field "cosmiconfig@8.2.0" is incompatible with requested version "cosmiconfig@^8.3.5"
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/visao/ckeditor5-video.git
Directory: /home/myproject
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
From my understanding this is an open repo.
Anyone else got this problem?
